# How to copy a range and paste unique values ascending

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I'm trying to copy a list of dates (with duplicates) and paste only unique values to another sheet. I can get the unique values, but the code below is missing the sort function.

```
Sub unique_dates()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D600").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H4"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Advanced filter does not have a built-in setting to sort the results. That will require additional steps, for example like this:

```
Sub unique_dates()
Dim lrow As Long, sortRange As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D600").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H4"), Unique:=True
    lrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Set sortRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H4:H" & lrow)

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H4"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange sortRange
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I've changed my worksheet a little and modified this code to apply to dates. The only issue I'm having now is that it isn't sorting the dates properly. It appears to be sorting by time instead of date. Any idea how to rectify??                            7/30/2019 6:45:00 AM - - -  304
7/30/2019 8:30:00 AM - - -  312
7/30/2019 8:23:00 AM - - -  308
7/30/2019 8:30:00 AM - - -  310
7/30/2019 12:30:00 PM - - -  302
7/29/2019 3:00:00 PM - - -  955
7/30/2019 3:00:00 PM - - -  945
7/29/2019 3:00:00 PM - - -  925
7/30/2019 8:20:00 AM - - -  314

Comment: Please don't put data samples into comments. They're hard to read. Edit your question and post something that makes it clear what is in a cell and by what column your data is sorted.